# How to put an array into \todo?

Tags: tables, todonotes

Consider the code

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{todonotes}
\begin{document}
%\todo{
\begin{tabular}{l}X\end{tabular}
  %}
\end{document}
```

I want the contents of the table (above: X), to be inside \todo, whether inlined or not. This feature would be useful, e.g., for putting matrices into todo boxes, of course, with arrays in math mode. However, pdflatex complains when I remove the comment symbols %. What to do?

Comment: The argument to `\todo` is a “moving” one; `\begin` and `\end` need to be prefixed by `\protect`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See [What is the difference between Fragile and Robust commands?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/4736/what-is-the-difference-between-fragile-and-robust-commands)

The argument of `\todo` is written in the `.aux` file because it is used for the “list of todos”, so it is a *moving argument* in which fragile commands need to be prefixed by `\protect`; `\begin` and `\end` are the prototypes of fragile commands.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{todonotes}

\begin{document}

\todo{%
  \protect\begin{tabular}{l}X\protect\end{tabular}%
}

\end{document}
```